# 1970s/80s YA or children's novel -- girl travels through time, inhabits body of another girl in 1600/1700s

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Girl has moved to a new town in UK with her mother. She's not adjusting well and goes for a walk where she discovers a primitive village with a young girl about her age. Eventually they meet and sort of merge(?). The girl from the past is called "Ann" and she has a little brother or sister that she has primary responsibility for.

I've searched endlessly on goodreads for a title and cover that look familiar and haven't turned up anything.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE. Take a look at [this guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152408/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Although the girl wasn't called Ann, it sounds vaguely similar to Moondial by Helen Cresswell - those of us who grew up in the UK in the 80s may more vividly recall the TV series. I haven't read it since 1988 so my memory may be a bit off!